# Slow running query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, navicat

I've recently come across a query which is taking abnormally long time from past few days. We had a server migration for MySQL database last month, and the problem never happened on the previous server. The MySQL version on the older server was 5.1.34 and on current one it's 5.1.58(not sure if that could have anything to do with this issue).

The query is as below:

```
 SELECT table_name,
       partition_name,
       subpartition_name,
       partition_method,
       subpartition_method,
       partition_expression,
       subpartition_expression,
       partition_description,
       partition_comment,
       nodegroup,
       tablespace_name
FROM   information_schema.partitions
WHERE  table_schema LIKE 'wialogdb'
       AND NOT Isnull(partition_name)
       AND table_name LIKE 'freemail'
ORDER  BY table_name,
          partition_name,
          partition_ordinal_position,
          subpartition_ordinal_position;
```

It's query on information_schema.PARTITIONS 
fired by Navicat to get the details about the table structure, it's very difucult to reproduce.

when you edit the table Navicat has to collect all the details abotu the table from Information Schema
(e.g lsit of Engines, Table Columns, see analyze Show Create table, etc)
and PARTITIONS is one of the table it has to check as you can see the WHERE condition is not "correct" WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'wialogdb' it should not be LIKE it should be WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'wialogdb', this query is much more faster, but it's Navicat's internal code
we can not change it. we didn't have this issues in the past (old MySQL 5.1.34)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a question for the DBA StackExchange site so I have flagged it to be moved there, but are your tables indexed? I would start by looking at that. If I recall correctly, you lose your indexing when you migrate a MySQL database, so you may have gone from a well indexed database, to one with no indexing.

Comment: How long is it taking? MySQL doesn't appear to index the information_schema tables, hence likely that query would land up on the slow query log even if it actually ran fairly quickly - depending on the settings for the slow query log (ie, whether it is just recording queries taking more than 1 second, or also logging unindexed queries)

Comment: Also browsing around I spotted this page - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/ . It mentions a setting which can cause slow queries when checking against the information schema. Possible the value of innodb_stats_on_metadata setting has changed between your 2 mysql installations.

Comment: @JMK...I checked it earlier, and found out that the tables are not indexed.

Also can u plz tell me if I had to migrate the databases without losing the indexes, how could I do so?(for futur ref.).

Comment: @Kickstart Earlier it used to get executed withing 2-3 seconds, but now it takes arnd 3-4 minutes, at times even longer.

Unindexed query logging is turned off, and time-limit for slow logging is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not your software, don't try to fix it. Let the creators know you have performance issues and that you have found something which can improve performance.

There's a reason why people buy licenses for software: use the support.

Comment: The reason why we cannot go back to the Software support is that the same query used to work fine before the migration so they would say it's got something to do with the Migration rather than the internal code of the software.

Comment: @dave005 You can always ask which steps you should take for migration, and maybe they are able to assist you.